# Visual Studio - Git Changes buttons aren't clickable

Tags: git, visual-studio

I've create a repository directly from Visual Studio using the button "Create Git Repository" in Git Changes.

While the solution stayed open, I was able to control Git and see changes and everything about. But after I close and reopen Visual Studio, the menu shows the commands as if the repo didn't exist.
Plus, they are not clickable.

[image: Git Changes screenshot]

How can I do?

Comment: What does the git output window say?

Comment: Maybe a restart from Visual Studio might help…

Comment: Hi! I resolved deleting the .git folder from the solution path and recreating it via Git Changes menu. Strange...